# SVG files not working after switching website hosting to my NAS

Tags: .htaccess, svg

I'm now hosting my website off my personal NAS drive and everything seems to be working except the SVGs.

I tried adding the .htaccess file with:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

but they still do not work. When I go to the URL of the file it just shows an error as if the file does not exist.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do your browser developer tools say?  Press F12 and go to the Net/Network tab.  Reload the file and check for MIME type and errors.

Comment: It shows a 404 error for the SVG files and their type is document.

Comment: If you are getting a 404, then either the URL is wrong, or the the file permissions are wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think the URL is wrong, proof being that when I do 'open url' from the file in cyberduck I get the error (I've also triple checked it). I also checked the file's permissions and it says 777 which looks like it's allowing everything.

Comment: Are you serving from a web server, or from `file://`?  If the latter, and you are using Chrome, you may be hitting against Chrome's security model. Try another browser.

Comment: I think the former, and I tried in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and it doesn't work in any of them.

Comment: So I just got it to work by moving the files from the subfolder (icons/email.svg) to the root. No idea why they wouldn't work in the subfolder. I tried having an .htaccess file in there as well as the root with no luck.